# Passing scope in on 'click' callback function angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="EditApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1 click-to-edit>This is something I want to edit</h1>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module("EditApp", [])
.controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.text = "This is something I would like to edit";

}])
.directive("clickToEdit", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: " <input type='text' value='{{ text }}' ng-show='showInput'/> <div ng-transclude ng-hide='showInput'></div>",
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.showInput = false
      element.on("click", function(){

        scope.$parent.showInput = true

      })
    } 
  }
})
```

Why is the `showInput` not changing? Or is it but I have to do a `scope.$apply()` ? Should I be passing in the `scope` somehow within the on click function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach an `ng-click` on the transclusion container, and you don't need to use `$parent` on scope as well. And yes it is not updating because

- you are updating wrong scope.
- angular does not know about the scope being updated from the handler registered externally unless you do, or until next digest cycle refresh will not happen :-

  `element.on("click", function(){
       scope.showInput = true
       scope.$apply();
     });`

Try:-

```
.directive("clickToEdit", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: " <input type='text' value='{{ text }}' ng-show='showInput'/> <div  ng-click='showClick()' ng-transclude ng-hide='showInput'></div>",
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.showInput = false;
      scope.showClick = function(){
         scope.showInput = true
      }
    } 
  }
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HRdouC?p=preview)**

[Plnkr2 update text on blur](http://plnkr.co/edit/BYi9eX?p=preview)

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly - cannot believe I didn't think of ngclicks

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy As much as possibly I would suggest to go with angular way of registering events so you don't end up with scope synchronization issues like these.. :)